# is there any built in function in Hive that calculates intersection of two lists in a hive table?

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have a hive table that have 3 columns : ["merchants_index", "weeks_index", "customer_index"]. The final goal is to calculate the percentage of repeat customers for each merchant in each week. By customer being repeat, I mean, for example, the customer that shopped at a merchant and week 10 also shopped at the same merchant in the previous 4 weeks (weeks 6-9).

Here is my approach:

step 1, create a list of customers in current week and another list of customers in the prev 4 weeks for each merchant and each week.

```
select 
merchant_index, 
week_index, 
collect_set(customer_index) over(partition by merchants_index range between 0 preceding and current row) AS uniq_cust_current,
collect_set(customer_index) over(partition by merchants_index range between 4 preceding and 0 preceding) AS uniq_cust_repeat
from
source_table
```

step 2, using Spark, map to the hive table a python function that calculates the wanted percentage by comparing the two lists for each row of the hive table.

The python function is like this:

```
len(numpy.intersect1d(uniq_cust_current, uniq_cust_repeat))* 1.0/ len(uniq_cust_current)
```

Also, I only have built-in functions in hive and spark available.

The reason why I get both Hive and spark involved is that I don't know how to compare lists on Hive and I don't know how to do a moving window calculation in Spark.

However, because the hive table is huge, over 100M rows, the output of the first step demands way too much memory thus the job gets killed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Spark function [`array_intersect`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array_intersect):

> array_intersect(array1, array2) - Returns an array of the elements in the intersection of array1 and array2, without duplicates.

Comment: Thanks! However, it does not solve the problem that the intermediary table between hive and spark being too large. I am wondering how to do it without generating the intermediary table

Answer (score 0):

In Hive you can use [brickhouse](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse) [intersect_array](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/wiki/Collect-UDFs) UDF 
This function is not built-in, you need to download and build JAR, then after adding JAR you can create function and use it:

```
 CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION intersect_array AS 'brickhouse.udf.collect.ArrayIntersectUDF';

select intersect_array(array1, array2, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks! But I only have access to the built in spark functions.